# UIAlertView Dismiss Returns to Home Screen

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, segue, uialertview

My app starts with a "home screen" navigation controller that sits in its own storyboard, and can segue to different storyboards, each beginning with a new navigation controller.  One of my secondary storyboards has a paywall.  When the user elects to dismiss the paywall without making a purchase, all I've been able to accomplish is dismissing the paywall and displaying the root view controller of the storyboard that requires a purchase.  I'm trying to send the user back to the "home screen" where they can see other content or segue to a different storyboard.

```
[PaywallManager registerBlockingPaywallClosedHandler:^{
  UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Blocked Paywall Closed" message:@"Return to home screen without purchase." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        
  UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
    [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:^{
    }]
  }];
  
  [alertController addAction:okAction];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
  [rootViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:true completion:^{}];
}];
```

When the user dismisses the UIAlertView by pressing the OK button, I need to segue back to the main navigation controller (home screen).  Currently when the user dismisses the UIAlertView, they get access to the paid content.  If I remove the closed handler, the app gets stuck on the paywall until a purchase is made or the user kills the app. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am still struggling with Objective-C and haven't had time to learn Swift so please go easy on me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The solution is here:

```
    [PaywallManager registerBlockingPaywallClosedHandler:^{
      UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"No Purchase Made" message:@"Return to the Home screen without purchase." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            
      UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
          [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }];
      
      [alertController addAction:okAction];
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
```